# Obter conteúdo que está entre parênteses usando regex

Tags: php, regex

Eu tenho estudando bastante o *regex*, mas me peguei tentando "limpar" um texto, deixando apenas a primeira ocorrência, e os dados entre parênteses, a *string* está assim:

```
$string = "Mais de - valor: R$3.21 - Tipo: (+05)";
```

Como todo o texto antes de `valor`, tem um `-` separando-os, eu usei o `explode`:

```
$string2 = explode("-", $string);
```

Obtenho então, o `Mais de`, queria juntar o `(+05)` a este resultado, mas nos códigos que já tentei com `preg_match` só me retorna o `(05)` sem o `+`, lembrando que este simbolo de mais pode ser também um simbolo de menos `-`, tipo `(-05)`, alguém sabe como delimito aspas em *regex*?
eu quero que o resultado final seja algo como:

> Mais de (+05)

Ao invés da `string` original.

Pra quem me ajudar, favor comente seu código pra mim tentar entender.

Comment: Coloque o *resultado final* que você quer. Eu não entendi o que deseja fazer...

Comment: Desculpa, atualizei a pergunta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar [somente uma regex](https://regex101.com/r/dB1nZ0/1) para isso: `/^([^-]+)[^\(]+(\([^\)]+\))/`

Nesse caso não precisas do explode e podes usar somente:

```
$string = "Mais de - valor: R$3.21 - Tipo: (+05)";
preg_match('/^([^-]+)[^\(]+(\([^\)]+\))/', $string, $match);
echo $match[1].$match[2];
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/xMVydh

A regex que usei tem 2 grupos de captura.
No primeiro, `[^-]+` aceita *n* caracteres que não sejam `-` para limitar até o `-` que atualmente usas para o explode.
No segundo, `\([^\)]+\)`, ele procura parenteses que têm de ser escapados e aceita n caracteres que não seja `)`, i.e. até encontrar o fecho de parenteses.

Comment: Consegui entender! muito obrigado Sergio!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isto sem utilizar *regex*:

```
$texto = "Mais de - valor: R$3.21 - Tipo: (+05)";

$parte1 = strstr($texto, "-", true);     // Retorna a 1ª ocorrência antes de "-"

$inicio = strpos($texto, "(");           // Encontra a posição da 1ª ocorrência do "("
$fim = strpos($texto, ")", $inicio) + 1; // Encontra a posição da 1ª ocorrência de ")" após "("

$parte2 = substr($texto, $inicio, $fim - $inicio);

echo $parte1 . $parte2 . "\n";           // Mais de (+05)
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/dn3YsX)

Utilize expressões regulares apenas se for realmente necessário.

Comment: Usando tanto `strstr` e `strpos` ainda compensa mais que ER? Dúvida real.

Comment: @PapaCharlie A documentação do [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-notes) - seção Notas cita: *Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use `strpos()` or `strstr()` instead as they **will be faster.*** =)

Comment: @qmechanik muito boa sua solução, certamente a usarei, pois já sabia que o `strpos()` e `strstr()` são mais rápidos. mas seguindo a lógica da pergunta, a do @Sergio se adequou melhor, isso ajudará outras pessoas que tem dúvidas sobre ER. mas obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Se `(+05)` for sempre fixo, você pode usar os últimos 5 caracteres.

```
$str = 'Mais de - valor: R$3.21 - Tipo: (+05)';
echo strstr( $str , ' - ' , true ) . ' ' . substr( $str , -5 );
```

**Output** : Mais de (+05)

[Demo](http://ideone.com/qLpaPD)

Comment: O (+05) não é estático, mas sua solução também é boa!